# How can I fix Visual Studio error "The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid."

Tags: visual-studio, build, ide

So when I try to open my project I get an error saying this:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVyDk.png)

I really need help, because I have no backup, and it took me a while to do this program.

Comment: Well, the csproj file is corrupt. Open it e.g. with notepad++ and see it it seems repairable. If not, create a new project and add all your sources using Add Existing Item.

Comment: Hi, I opened the CSPROJECT and all I see in there is a letter s. What should I do?

Comment: Like @Klaus said, you need to create a new project and add all your source files using Add Existing Item

Comment: Mkay, it worked. Thank you.